# 'Spree' as a figure of speech

Tags: grammar

I came across the following sentence in a book by the English nature writer Robert Macfarlane;

> Sunlight fell in bright sprees on the floor (of the wood).

What part of speech is 'spree' in this context. It's a noun of some sort, but can anyone help more specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Macfarlane's use of the word spree in that way is called *catachresis* in rhetoric.  Catachresis is a seemingly outlandish, implied metaphor which uses words in highly unusual ways.  Catachresis, as Robert A. Harris observed, is "difficult to invent, but it can be wonderfully effective."

A few examples might help:

> Shakespeare in Hamlet:  "I will speak daggers to her."

Or,

> Me (adapted from Jim Gaffigan):  Moses:  "Aaron, you wouldn't believe what just happened!  God talked to me from a burning bush!"  Aaron:  "Yeah, right, Moses.  I think you've been burning a little bush" (Aaron imitates taking a toke).

Or,

> Crystal Gayle song:  "Don't it make my brown eyes blue."

That last one may be a bit of a stretch, and it may be a combination of rhetorical figures, but it is an unusual use of the word *blue*.

Answer (score 2):

You have identified that *spree* is a noun.

While *spree* is defined by OED as "an occasion or spell of somewhat disorderly or noisy enjoyment (freq. accompanied by drinking). Also *transf.* and as shopping spree, spending spree, etc.", that is preceded by

> A lively or boisterous frolic;

It is possible to imagine light dancing across the floor as if it were alive, in a boisterous frolic, especially if it is filtered through moving trees.

Comment: The light tripping? Fantastic.

Comment: I did ask a well-informed American guide in Berlin, whether the English expression 'going out on the Spree' had anything to do with  that City's main river. I had thought of it as a 1920s thing, when Berlin was a swinging city. But apparently it dates from the 18th century and the origin is unknown.

Comment: I had thought it might be a relatively modern amalgam of 'spending' and 'free' ??!